# Postgresql - Timezones when date range crossses into BST

Tags: postgresql, timezone

I have a very simple table that contains a start_date field (`timestampz`) that stores a `UTC datetime` value. I need to return the dates contained in the table, adjusted for `British Summer Time`(BST), but the problem i'm having is that AT TIME ZONE `BST` adds 1 hour to `UTC` dates irrespective of their value; If the date happened in `February` (before BST started), the `UTC` value is the correct value. If the date value is from `March` (after BST started), then the `UTC` value needs `+01` added to it.

**Table Data**

```
2014-02-16 00:00:000+00
2014-04-16 00:00:000+00

SELECT start_date AT TIME ZONE 'BST' from t1
```

adds + 01 hour to both values

```
2014-02-16 00:01:000
2014-04-16 00:01:000
```

Is there a simple way to achieve the following?;

```
2014-02-16 00:00:000
2014-04-16 00:01:000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BST` is by definition `UTC+01:00`. So it works as expected. [Use](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datetime-keywords.html) `Europe/London` to get results you want.